# What causes a glass block to crack? Does it cause any structural damage?

Tags: repair, crack

I just found that there is a crack in one of my glass blocks. I noticed that it seems to have water inside. What is the likely cause of this, and how can I repair it?  Should I be worried about structural damage?

Comment: If water got in, could it have frozen? Seems unlikely if you are in the northern hemisphere this time of year.

Answer (score 1):

It's glass...it's a fairly rigid material and will not flex like other potential building materials such as wood, mortar, etc. So, if the house settled, the block may simply have been under enough stress to crack it.

Or, maybe someone shot it with a BB gun.

Comment: Or a rock hit it (maybe thrown from a lawnmower)?